# enable validation on objects that are embedded

Tags: symfony

I need help to know how to validate a property that is embedded to an object but which is not required. I mean that I want to validate this embedded property only if its value is not null.

For example, in the documentation of Symfony 3, you have 2 entities Author and Address. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

To validate address, you must add @Assert\Valid() to address property in Author entity. I'm OK with that. If the property address is absolutely required,  it's good.

But how about the case that the property address is not required at all, each time I submit the form without fill the address fields, I will get errors because the @assert/Valid() on address property in Author entity.

How I can deal with that ?
Thanks

Comment: Can't you just `return true;` in your function if it's empty?

Comment: What are the other constraints you put on your address entity?

Comment: I could make it work as expected by adding in my User controller, in the action where I create the User form, the group "Address" : 'validation_groups' => ['Profile', 'Address']. my User entity extending from FOSUserBundle.
Now, when the Address property is null, it's ok. If the property Address is not null, I will get errors if fields from Address are not filled correctly.

The new problem that I have now is when I update the User datas. If I make empty every fields from Address, I can't submit because I get every errors from the constraints I set in my Address entity. I am  looking why that.